# Compare part of string in javascript lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, picklist, array

I have a List which is filtered by the comparison of the value of a picklist (for example A) and selected value of a checkbox (for example A) which works ok.

I want to be able to compare a multiselect picklist value (A;B;C;D) with the selected value of a check box (value A).

My current comparison

```
var  opleidingfilter = opleidingenList.filter(function(item) { return item[fieldName] == event.getSource().get('v.text') });
```

Is there in Javascript something like

```
item[fieldName] == '%'+ JSON.stringify(event.getSource().get('v.text')) +'%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` method. This method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

```
var str = JSON.stringify(event.getSource().get('v.text'));
return str.indexOf(item[fieldName]) != -1;
```

If a non-negative value is returned, it means that the string is found and otherwise its not found. Also, `indexOf` is case sensitive, you might want to use `toLowerCase` before comparison if you want to do a case insensitive comparison.